# PHP curl is changing JSON before posting it

Tags: php, python, django, curl

I have an API written in django, which is able to process the following request correctly.

```
curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"name":"a","description":"b","props":    {"Notes":"c"}}' http://127.0.0.1:8000/en/api/asset/ -H 'Authorization: Token     114ada7e487b2cdbc9277d377e4d20640a606bb2'
```

If I print request.DATA at the Django side I get the following:

```
(Pdb) print request.DATA
{u'props': {u'Notes': u'c'}, u'name': u'a', u'description': u'b'}
```

I have the following piece of PHP code which I want to use to make the exact same request

```
$data_string = json_encode($values['json_parameters']);
error_log($data_string, 0);
//curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, $method);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
    'Content-Type: application/json',
    'Content-Length: ' . strlen($data_string))
);
error_log("Method: ".$method, 0);
if ($method == 'POST') {
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data_string);
}
```

$data_string contains {"name":"a","description":"b","props":{"Notes":"c"}}.

When this query hits the backend I get the following:

```
(Pdb) print request.DATA
<QueryDict: {u'{"name":"a","description":"b","props":{"Notes":"c"}}': [u'']}>
```

What is PHP doing to my JSON before it sends it? How can I post the exact same data using PHP as per my curl request above?

- It does work for requests that don't have nested JSON

Comment: Ah, you were asking something different; now that I fixed the formatting to reveal the querydict.

Comment: I doubt *PHP* is *doing* anything. Especially since `$data_string` is correct. The better question is what are *you* doing? Did you sniff the traffic to see if PHP is indeed sending what Python receives?

Comment: I am certain that PHP is not doing what my original curl script is doing, and that is what I want it to do. I have not sniffed the data. The request from curl, swidt, java, angular and python work as expected.

Answer (score 0):

I'm no PHP expert, but it may not matter: if `request.DATA` is a `QueryDict`, you can simply use `arealdict = request.DATA.dict()` to get a real `dict` out of it.   Should there be any repeated fields this will pick just one of their multiple values, but that shouldn't matter for your specific use case since it seems to have no repeated fields anyway.

Comment: I am doing that, but the result is a dict where all the key values are in the key field. I cannot change the server side. I might just swap out PHP for another language that I am more familiar with.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that I was overwriting the application/json header later on in my login code. That is why some requests appeared to work fine.

Sinc eteh content type was not set, Django treated the request as a form post which resulted in the mangled request.DATA.